# Django Class-Based Generic Views and ModelForms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

Like much documentation on generic views in Django, I can't find docs that explicitly describe how to use the new Class-Based Generic Views with Django Forms.

How is it done?

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried so far? The class based views are pretty new, and the docs don't have a lot of examples, so I think you're going to need to get your hands dirty and experiment!

If you want to update an existing object, then try using [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#updateview). Look at the mixins it uses (e.g [`ModelFormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#modelformmixin), [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#singleobjectmixin), [`FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin)) to see which methods you can/have to override.

Good luck!

Comment: UpdateView looks to be what I need. If I understand the docs you linke dot correctly, I don't even need to write a separate subclass for my form(s). My problem is that I am fairly new to Django, so some actual working examples would really help me. thanks for the links though.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use model forms with class based views is to pass in the model and keep a slug / pk captured in url, in which case you will not need to write any view code.

```
url(r'^myurl/$', CreateView.as_view(model=mymodel)) 
#Creates a model form for model mymodel

url(r'^myurl/(?<pk>\w+)/$', UpdateView.as_view(model=mymodel)) 
#Creates a model form for model mymodel and updates the object having pk as specified in url

url(r'^myurl/(?<slug>\w+)/$', DeleteView.as_view(model=mymodel, slug_field="myfield")) 
#Creates a model form for model mymodel and deletes the object denoted by mymodel.objects.get(my_field=slug)
```

You can also override methods to obtain more complex logic. You can also pass a queryset instead of a model object.

Another way is to create a modelform in forms.py and then pass form_class to the url as

```
url(r'^myurl/$', CreateView.as_view(form_class=myform))
```

This method allows you to define form functions as well as Meta attributes for the form.

Comment: How would one use a generic version of create to add an "entry" to class "category"?   class Category(models.Model): title           = models.CharField) slug            = models.CharField() entry           = models.ManyToManyField(Entry)

Comment: url(r'^myurl/$', CreateView.as_view(model=Category, template_name="template.html"))